# Makefile can't find my .cpp dependancy file

Tags: c++, makefile

[Files](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LnCC3.png) [makefile.vars](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ksI6N.png) I'm trying to compile 4 .cpp files and a header, while running through the compilation process so I can get the object files and the assembly file but the makefile is giving me an error that it can't find my original .cpp file.
"No rule to make target Add.cpp needed by Add.s. Stop."

```
#include "makefile.vars"
$(Bin)Main: $(Objects)Add.o $(Objects)Subtract.o $(Objects)Multiply.o $(Objects)common.o $(Objects)Main.o
    $(GCC) $(Objects)Add.o
    $(Objects)Subtract.o
    $(Objects)Multiply.o
    $(Objects)common.o
    $(Objects)Main.o
    -o $(Bin)Main
clean:
    rm -rf $(Bin)/* $(Objects)/* $(Pre)/* $(Assembly)/*

$(Assembly)Add.s: $(Source)Add.cpp
    $(GCC) $(DEBUG) $(GCC_FLAGS) $(INCLUDES) -S  -o $(Source)Add.cpp  $(Assembly)Add.s
$(Assembly)Add.o: $(Source)Add.s
    $(GCC) $(DEBUG) $(GCC_FLAGS) $(INCLUDES) -c -o $(Assembly)Add.s $(Objects)Add.o

$(Assembly)Subtract.s: $(Source)Subtract.cpp
    $(GCC) $(DEBUG) $(GCC_FLAGS) $(INCLUDES) -S -o $(Source)Subtract.cpp  $(Assembly)Subtract.s
$(Assembly)Subtract.o: $(Source)Subtract.s
    $(GCC) $(DEBUG) $(GCC_FLAGS) $(INCLUDES) -c -o $(Assembly)Subtract.s $(Objects)Subtract.o

$(Assembly)Multiply.s: $(Source)Multiply.cpp
    $(GCC) $(DEBUG) $(GCC_FLAGS) $(INCLUDES) -S -o $(Source)Multiply.cpp  $(Assembly)Multiply.s
$(Assembly)/Multiply.o: $(Source)/Multiply.s
    $(GCC) $(DEBUG) $(GCC_FLAGS) $(INCLUDES) -c -o $(Assembly)Multiply.s $(Objects)Multiply.o

$(Assembly)Main.s: $(Source)Main.cpp
    $(GCC) $(DEBUG) $(GCC_FLAGS) $(INCLUDES) -S -o $(Source)Main.cpp  $(Assembly)Main.s
$(Assembly)/Main.o: $(Source)/Main.s
    $(GCC) $(DEBUG) $(GCC_FLAGS) $(INCLUDES) -c -o $(Assembly)Main.s  $(Objects)Main.o

$(Assembly)common.s: $(Header)common.h
    $(GCC) $(DEBUG) $(GCC_FLAGS) $(INCLUDES) -S -o $(Header)common.h  $(Assembly)common.s
$(Assembly)common.o: $(Source)common.s
    $(GCC) $(DEBUG) $(GCC_FLAGS) $(INCLUDES) -c -o $(Assembly)common.s $(Objects)common.o
```

I want my files to be object files in the end that I can link.

Comment: Well the obvious question is do you have a file called Add.cpp (case matters BTW) in the same place as all the other files? Another question, does your makefile work without the Add rules, or do you get the same error on the next file? Have you ever had some version of this makefile working? If so what was the change you made that stopped it working? You have to help us to help you by providing as much information as possible.

Comment: @john I apologize for not including this information. This is my first time making a makefile. The source folder contains all these files with the same spelling (Case is the same). Tried it just now. If I delete the Add rules, I get the same error for the Subtract. I'll add some pictures of the folders and the vars file.

Comment: I'm not seeing `Source` variable definition in `makefile.vars`. It only has `Sources`.

Comment: So it seems it's not finding any files. So the likely problem is the value of the $(Source) and $(Assembly) variables

Comment: @HolyBlackCat Yep, I saw that and fixed it. The same error message is appearing

Comment: There's no $(Assembly) variable in your makefile.vars either

Comment: @john I added a $(Assembly) variable and I put the $(Source) variable and the same problem occurs.

Comment: Exact same error message? The error message should at least include the value you entered for the $(Sources) variable now.

Comment: @john This is the exact error message. Hasn't changed. make: *** No rule to make target 'Add.cpp', needed by 'Add.s'.  Stop.

Answer (score 3):

Your problem is you're using the C/C++ preprocessor `#include` in a makefile.  Makefiles are not C/C++ code.

In a makefile, a `#` introduces a comment line, so the rest of the line is ignored.

Also, make does not do anything special with quotes so you should not use them in non-recipe parts of makefiles (you should of course use them where needed in recipes, which are passed to the shell, because the shell *does* do special things with quotes).

Change:

```
#include "makefile.vars"
```

to:

```
include makefile.vars
```

**ETA**

Your next problem is because you have misused variables, so make can't create the dependency chain.  Consider these rules:

```
$(Bin)Main: $(Objects)Add.o ...
        ...
$(Assembly)Add.s: $(Source)Add.cpp
        ...
$(Assembly)Add.o: $(Source)Add.s
        ...
```

The first rule tells make it can create `$(Bin)Main` from `$(Objects)Add.o`.  The second says make can create `$(Assembly)Add.s` from `$(Source)Add.cpp`.  The last rule tells make it can create `$(Assembly)Add.o` from `$(Source)Add.s`.

None of these rules tell make how to create `$(Objects)Add.o` (assuming that the variables `Objects` and `Assembly` do not have the same value).

And if you fix that, then you'll get a failure because none of your rules tell make how to build `$(Source)Add.s` which is the prerequisite of `Add.o`.

You need to use the same variables for the same target in all places; the final rule should be:

```
$(Objects)Add.o: $(Assembly)Add.s
        ...
```

**ETA2**

Also your rules are wrong: you are using `-o $(Source)Add.cpp` so you are asking the compiler to generate output that will *overwrite* your source file.  I hope you see this edit before you fix your makefile enough to delete all your code.

**ETA3**

Your makefiles would be a lot simpler and a *lot* less prone to errors (and much easier to fix mistakes in) if you use [pattern rules](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Pattern-Rules.html) instead of duplicating all your text over and over; delete ALL your rules for building assembly and object files and add these two pattern rules:

```
(Assembly)%.s: $(Source)%.cpp
        $(GCC) $(DEBUG) $(GCC_FLAGS) $(INCLUDES) -S -o $@ $<
$(Objects)%.o: $(Assembly)%.s
        $(GCC) $(DEBUG) $(GCC_FLAGS) $(INCLUDES) -c -o $@ $<
```

Comment: Just goes to show you need experts to answer questions, not idiots like me.

Comment: Thank you so much. I removed the # and the quotes. Now the error says: make: *** No rule to make target '/home/wateracc123/Code/Object/Add.o', needed by '/home/wateracc123/Code/Bin/Main'.  Stop.

Comment: @john You didn't say anything wrong, I didn't have those variables and I didn't include enough details.

Comment: All you _really_ need is the documentation and/or a book. But hey.

Comment: @IbrahimEl-sayed Well I think I know that one. You have $(Assembly)Add.o and $(Objects)Add.o in different parts of your makefile. That's asking for trouble.

Comment: @john I feel so unbelievably stupid right now. I fixed that and now it gets me an error that there's no recipe for the target. There's something wrong with my switches, I'll figure it out.

Comment: @MadScientist Thank you so much for the help. I'm getting a recipe error at line 13               /usr/bin/g++ -g -std=c++11 -l /home/wateracc123/Code/Header    /home/wateracc123/Code/Source/Add.cpp  -S /home/wateracc123/Code/Assembly/Add.s

Comment: @MadScientist It still prints Makefile:15: recipe for target '/home/wateracc123/Code/Object/Add.o' failed
make: *** [/home/wateracc123/Code/Object/Add.o] Error 1
And, I think that means that there's something wrong with the actual line of code.

Comment: That means make ran your command, and it exited with an error code.  These messages are irrelevant.  There should have been errors BEFORE those messages, from the compiler telling you what is wrong with your code.  If you can't figure out how to fix those you should definitely open up a different question on StackOverflow, because it's not related to this question which has been answered.